# Como realizar um fadeIn em mais de um elemento no resultado de um Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo um arquivo para carregamento de novas notícias, no entanto, as novas notícias aparecem rapidamente sem uma entrada suave.

Sei que dá para utilizar algo deste tipo:

```
$(“.containerNews”).append(result).children(':last').hide().fadeIn();
```

No entanto este código pega apenas a última linha do resultado Ajax, e eu gostaria de fazer o efeito com `fadeIn` sempre nas últimas incrementações do Ajax.

Meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
 $(".SeeMoreGame").click(function(){

      $.ajax({
        url:"seeMoreGames.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{ searchValue: searchValue, numberRows: numberRows },
        success:function(result){
          $(".containerNews").append(result);
        }
      });

  });
```

Eu consegui achar uma solução para este problema com ajuda de um comentário que esta logo abaixo .
Caso alguém entre aqui porque está com o mesmo problema, basta adicionar uma class nos novos resultados que serão exibido, Exemplo:

```
<li class="hide"></li>
```

E antes do novo requerimento Ajax você remove esta classe. Exemplo:

```
 $(".SeeMoreGame").click(function(){
    $(".containerNews li").removeClass("hide");

      $.ajax({
        url:"seeMoreGames.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{ searchValue: searchValue, numberRows: numberRows },
        success:function(result){
          $(".containerNews").append(result);
          $(".hide").hide().fadeIn();
        }
      });

  });
```

Comment: Faça com que os novos elementos venham com uma classe, por exemplo: `<div class="hide">...</div>`. E então basta utilizar `$('.hide').fadeIn('slow')`

Comment: Mas a questão é, se eu utilizar uma class toda vez que carregar novos elementos tudo que tiver a class vai sofrer o efeito fadeIn de novo. É eu quero só nos novos elementos.
por exemplo nos últimos 6 elementos adicionados.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica eu consegui fazer mais ou menos do jeito que você falou, eu adicionei a class só que antes de executar o código novamente eu removi ela. Muito obrigado

Comment: que bom que conseguiu. Se possível, poste o código como resposta e reversa sua última edição. Dessa forma, você poderá marcar a questão como resolvida.

Comment: Tentei fazer mas não deu certo. Não mexo muito aqui então talvez seja falta praticada minha parte, Por enquanto vou deixar da forma que esta.

Answer (score 1):

Faça o append com os elementos já ocultos (acrescentando `display: none` com replace), e depois faça o `.fadeIn()` nos elementos que foram adicionados na lista:

Veja os comentários no código:

```
$(".SeeMoreGame").click(function(){

      $.ajax({
        url:"seeMoreGames.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{ searchValue: searchValue, numberRows: numberRows },
        success:function(result){
          // faz um replace no retorno adicionado display: none
          // em todas as LI's
          result = result.replace(/<li/g, '<li style="display: none"');
          $(".containerNews")
          .append(result) // faz o append
          .find(":hidden") // seleciona as LI's ocultas
          .fadeIn(); // faz o fadeIn em todas

        }
      });

});
```

Comment: Eu já tinha testado este esquema, só que ele faz o fadeIn em só uma <li></li>, e a minha intenção era colocar em  6 de uma só vez. Mas eu já obtive uma solução eu deixei logo acima.

Muito Obrigado por tentar ajudar!

Comment: Achei que era na última li adicionada.... vou alterar a resposta então, poderá servir para alguém no futuro. A propósito, o campo de perguntas não deve ser usado para colocar respostas. Abs!

Comment: Dá uma olhada agora.